# sending notification to my flutter app when mysql database is updated

Tags: flutter

I was to send a notification to my flutter app when a certain table is updated.

the find that I can connect it to firebase and it will be solved but my tables are already made and the app is about to finish I can't waste more time.

I came up with a solution that I send an HTTP request and check if there is anything new every minute, but it would cost a lot of Bytes so I wont to try something else.

is there a way to get the information when it is added or within a small time frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the socket io which will help to detect onUpdate